# Increasing a vote (in a list of saved URLs) doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have a list of URLs saved in a firebase DB, and I'm trying to simply add a count next to each url, so that users can like them. My $scope.increase function tries to serve that purpose but there must be something wrong, it should increase the count on click and also update the database. Can anyone help?

**HTML**

```
<li ng-repeat="url in urls | filter:todoSearch" class="list-item">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-8 link-col">

                  <a href="{{url.title}}" class="link">
                      <p class="title">{{url.name}}</p>
                      <p class="url">{{url.title}}</p>

                  </a>
                    <p ng-model="mvLikes" ng-click="increase($index)">0</p>
              </div>

        </div>
        </li>
```

**JS**

```
var urlFire = angular.module("UrlFire", ["firebase"]);
function MainController($scope, $firebase) {
  $scope.favUrls = $firebase(new Firebase('https://lloydyapp.firebaseio.com/'));
  $scope.urls = [];
  $scope.favUrls.$on('value', function() {
      $scope.urls = [];
      var mvs = $scope.favUrls.$getIndex();
        for (var i = 0; i < mvs.length; i++) {
          $scope.urls.unshift({
            name: $scope.favUrls[mvs[i]].name,
            title: $scope.favUrls[mvs[i]].title,
            likes: $scope.favUrls[mvs[i]].likes,
            key: mvs[i]
          });
        };
    });

$scope.increase = function(index) {
    $scope.mvLikes += 1;
    var mvLikes  = $scope.mvLikes;

    var mv = $scope.urls[index];
    var updateUrlRef = buildEndPoint(mv.key, $firebase);
    updateUrlRef.$set({
      likes: mvLikes
    });

}

....
function buildEndPoint(key, $firebase) {
return $firebase(new Firebase('https://lloydyapp.firebaseio.com/' + key));
}
```

Comment: From what point do you experience a problem? Have you logged `$scope.mvLikes` to check it's value?

Comment: No `ng-model` on `<p>`. Doesn't make sense only having one `mvLikes` when you want to show individual likes